# Saving SEC 10-K annual report text to files (trouble with decoding)

Tags: parsing, edgar

I am trying to bulk-download the text visible to the "end-user" from 10-K SEC Edgar reports (don't care about tables) and save it in a text file. I have found the code below on Youtube, however I am facing 2 challenges:

1. I am not sure if I am capturing all text, and when I print the URL from below, I receive very weird output (special characters e.g., at the very end of the print-out)
2. I can't seem to save the text in `txt` files, not sure if this is due to encoding (I am entirely new to programming).

```
import re
import requests
import unicodedata
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def restore_windows_1252_characters(restore_string):
    def to_windows_1252(match):
        try:
            return bytes([ord(match.group(0))]).decode('windows-1252')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # No character at the corresponding code point: remove it.
            return ''

    return re.sub(r'[\u0080-\u0099]', to_windows_1252, restore_string)

# define the url to specific html_text file
new_html_text = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000796343-14-000004.txt"

# grab the response
response = requests.get(new_html_text)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html5lib')

page_text = page_soup.html.body.get_text(' ',strip = True)

# normalize the text, remove characters. Additionally, restore missing window characters.
page_text_norm = restore_windows_1252_characters(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', page_text)) 

# print: this works however gives me weird special characters in the print (e.g., at the very end)
print(page_text_norm)

# save to file: this only gives me an empty text file
with open('testfile.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(page_text_norm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you take the data you expect as an example, it will be easier for people to understand your needs.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000796343-14-000004.txt'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# text = doc.body.text
text = doc.body.unescape() # Converting HTML entities
utils.saveFile("testfile.txt",text)
```

Comment: @dernuco If it's what you want, mark it as the answer, which can also help others. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @dabingsou, is there a way to include a delay for long loading time? E.g., this link takes a lot of time to be fully loaded, when I save the .txt, it contains only the first few lines: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000104746919000788/0001047469-19-000788.txt

Comment: @dernuco I don't have a good way either. Try this way to see if it works: req.get(url,timeout=300)